# What's the safest way to shut down MongoDB when running as a Windows Service?

Tags: windows, mongodb

I have a single instance of MongoDB 2.4.8 running on Windows Server 2012 R2. MongoDB is installed as a Windows Service. I have journalling enabled.

The [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#tutorial-mongod-as-windows-service) suggests that the MongoDB service should just be shut down via the Windows Service Control Manager:

```
net stop MongoDB
```

When I did this recently, the following was logged and I ended up with a non-zero byte mongod.lock file on disk. (I used the --repair option to fix this but it turns out this probably wasn't necessary as I had journalling enabled.)

```
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.011 [serviceShutdown] got SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP request from Windows Service Control Manager, will terminate after current cmd ends
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [serviceShutdown] now exiting
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 dbexit: 
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [serviceShutdown] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [serviceShutdown] closing listening socket: 1492
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [serviceShutdown] closing listening socket: 1500
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [serviceShutdown] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [serviceShutdown] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [serviceShutdown] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [serviceShutdown] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [serviceShutdown] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [conn1333] end connection 127.0.0.1:51612 (18 connections now open)
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [conn1331] end connection 127.0.0.1:51610 (18 connections now open)
...snip...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [conn1322] end connection 10.1.2.212:53303 (17 connections now open)
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.043 [conn1337] end connection 127.0.0.1:51620 (18 connections now open)
Thu Nov 21 11:08:12.839 [serviceShutdown] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:14.683 [serviceShutdown]       Progress: 5/163 3%  (File Closing Progress)
Thu Nov 21 11:08:16.012 [serviceShutdown]       Progress: 6/163 3%  (File Closing Progress)
...snip...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:52.030 [serviceShutdown]       Progress: 143/163   87% (File Closing Progress)
Thu Nov 21 11:08:54.092 [serviceShutdown]       Progress: 153/163   93% (File Closing Progress)
Thu Nov 21 11:08:55.405 [serviceShutdown] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Nov 21 11:08:55.405 [serviceShutdown] journalCleanup...
Thu Nov 21 11:08:55.405 [serviceShutdown] removeJournalFiles
Thu Nov 21 11:09:05.578 [DataFileSync] ERROR: Client::shutdown not called: DataFileSync
```

The last line is my main concern.

I'm also interested in how MongoDB is able to take longer to shut down than Windows normally allows for service shutdown? At what point is it safe to shut down the machine without checking the log file?

Comment: This looks like an issue they've documented as being fixed. I'd suggest opening a ticket for it. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2719

Comment: And, services can request to have an extended shutdown period. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I've created a ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11826